# Discord Slash Command Lambda Bot Not Working Only for One Server

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot that is set up with aws lambda and api gateway. It was working in one of my servers and out of nowhere stopped working. When using commands from a DM or from my other server, they work just fine. When using it from my production server with members, it gives a (Signature was forged or corrupt) error. Only from one server. I did not change permissions as far as I know and this randomly started happening, it was working about 2 weeks ago. I have looked all over and no one has been able to answer as to why it is happening, and discord support has been no help. Code used to verify below. If you need more code, let me know. Again, it works in another server & DMs but not my main server, which is affecting my community. This is serverless and does not require discord.py to work.

```
body = json.loads(event['body'])
  signature = event['headers']['x-signature-ed25519']
  timestamp = event['headers']['x-signature-timestamp']
  # validate the interaction

  verify_key = VerifyKey(bytes.fromhex(PUBLIC_KEY))

  message = timestamp + json.dumps(body, separators=(',', ':'))
  try:
    verify_key.verify(message.encode(), signature=bytes.fromhex(signature))
  except BadSignatureError as e:
    print("BadSignatureError:", str(e))
    return {
      'statusCode': 401,
      'body': json.dumps('invalid request signature 401')
    }
```

There is more code but this is where it stops from my server. It is successful from others.

I have tried changing how I verify, I set up another API gateway, I even made a new app/bot to put into my server and again, only my server is affected. However, MEE6 slash commands still work in my server, so not a clue as to why mine do not work.

Comment: [Welcome to Stack Overflow.](/tour) Why is this downvoted? And please include the discord.py code. I might be able to help with the discord.py part if the problem is not with AWS.